# SQL Values to integers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to compare values in a database that are updated every time a user logs in.  When I execute a query with the given code nothing happens. However if I give it a value of say (where Attempt >10) it works where am I going wrong?

```
private void User_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con13 = new SqlConnection("Data Source = *** ")

    SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [User],[Login],[number1],[number2],[number3],[Alertcount] FROM Users.dbo.[Email] where [Alertcount] = 1 and [Alertcount] !=2", con13);

    DataTable Users = new DataTable();
    DataTable DATA2 = new DataTable();

    SDA2.Fill(DATA2);

    dataGridView2.DataSource = DATA2;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        string col2 = 1.Cells["User"].Value.ToString();
        string col1 = 1.Cells["Login"].Value.ToString();
        string col3 = 1.Cells["number1"].Value.ToString();
        string col4 = 1.Cells["number2"].Value.ToString();
        string col5 = 1.Cells["number3"].Value.ToString();
        string col6 = 1.Cells["Alertcount"].Value.ToString();

        var mine = Convert.ToInt32(col3);
        var mine2 = Convert.ToInt32(col5);

        SqlConnection CON2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ***")
        CON2.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [User],[Login],[Attempt] FROM User.dbo.Actions where  [Attempt] >  '"+mine+ "' and [Attempt] < '" + mine2 + "'", CON2);

        DataTable DATA = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DATA);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column `Attempt` is an integer (as evident from the fact that `Attempt < 10` runs), you need not pass comparison values to it in string. So your query should be like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [User],[Login],[Attempt] FROM User.dbo.Actions where  [Attempt] >  "+mine+ " and [Attempt] < " + mine2 , CON2);
```

I would suggest you to debug such errors in future by creating a query variable and then running the query in SQL manually to see what the error is. You could do something like this:

```
var query = "SELECT [User],[Login],[Attempt] FROM User.dbo.Actions where  [Attempt] >  "+mine+ " and [Attempt] < " + mine2 ;
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query , CON2);
```

Answer (score 0):

*nothing happens* - not enough information for correct answer. If actually nothing happens, then remove all `try catch` blocks you have around code and run application again. Then if something wrong you will get very useful information about what gone wrong in the form of `Exception`.

However, problem seems is that you passing wrong data to database query.
**Always** use `SqlParameter` for passing dynamic data to the query. `SqlParameter` have type which you can set to correspondent type of column you want operate on. Also `SqlParameter` will protect you from sql injection.

Use `using` for disposable objects when ever it possible (read "always")

```
var emailQuery = 
    @"SELECT [User] ,[Login] ,[number1] ,[number2] ,[number3] ,[Alertcount] 
    FROM Users.dbo.[Email] 
    WHERE [Alertcount] = 1 
        AND [Alertcount] !=2"; // Useless condition, because Alertcount already = 1

using(var connection2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source = *** "))
using(var adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(emailQuery, connection1))
{
    var data2 = new DataTable();
    adapter2.Fill(data2);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = data2;
}

var actionsQuery = 
    @"SELECT [User] ,[Login] ,[Attempt] 
    FROM User.dbo.Actions 
    WHERE Attempt > @Mine AND Attempt < @Mine2";
foreach (var row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    var mine = (int)row.Cells["number1"].Value; // it is already integer, just cast it
    var mine2 = (int)row.Cells["number3"].Value;

    using(var connection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source = *** "))
    using(var adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(actionsQuery, connection1))
    {
        var parameters = new[]
        {
            new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Mine",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Value = mine
            },
            new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Mine2",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Value = mine2
            }
        };
        adapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        var data1 = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(data1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data1
    }        
}
```